# Identifying large bodies of text via BeautifulSoup or other python based extractors

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Given [some random news article](http://www.cnn.com/2013/01/04/justice/ohio-rape-online-video/index.html?hpt=hp_c2), I want to write a web crawler to find the largest body of text present, and extract it. The intention is to extract the physical news article on the page.

The original plan was to use a <strike>`BeautifulSoup findAll(True)`</strike> and to sort each tag by its `.getText()` value. **EDIT: don't use this for html work, use the lxml library, it's python based and much faster than BeautifulSoup.** command (which means extract all html tags)

But this won't work for most pages, like the one I listed as an example, because the large body of text is split into many smaller tags, like paragraph dividers for example.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Any help with something like this would be amazing.

At the moment I'm using BeautifulSoup along with python, but willing to explore other possibilities.

---

**EDIT: Came back to this question after a few months later (wow i sounded like an idiot ^), and solved this with a combination of libraries & own code.**

Here are some deadly helpful python libraries for the task in sorted order of how much it helped me:

#1 [goose library](https://github.com/grangier/python-goose) Fast, powerful, consistent
#2 [readability library](https://github.com/gfxmonk/python-readability) Content is passable, slower on average than goose but faster than boilerpipe
#3 [python-boilerpipe](https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe) Slower & hard to install, no fault to the boilerpipe library (originally in java), but to the fact that this library is build on top of another library in java, which attributes to IO time & errors, etc.

I'll release benchmarks perhaps if there is interest.

---

**Indirectly related libraries, you should probably install them and read their docs:**

- [NLTK text processing library](http://nltk.org/) **This
  is too good not to install. They provide text analysis tools along
  with html tools (like cleanup, etc).**
- [lxml html/xml parser](http://lxml.de/) **Mentioned
  above. This beats BeautifulSoup in every aspect but usability. It's a
  bit harder to learn but the results are worth it. HTML parsing takes
  much less time, it's very noticeable.**
- [python
  webscraper library](https://code.google.com/p/webscraping/source/browse/) **I think the value of this code isn't the
  lib itself, but using the lib as a reference manual to build your own
  crawlers/extractors. It's very nicely coded / documented!**

A lot of the value and power in using python, a rather slow language, comes from it's open source libraries. They are especially awesome when combined and used together, and everyone should take advantage of them to solve whatever problems they may have!

Goose library gets lots of solid maintenance, they just added Arabic support, it's great!

Comment: What has the choice of a parser to do with your problem? What is actually your problem?

Comment: I suppose the problem is how to extract the text of an article from the page and leave all the rubbish, like menus, links to other articles, ads, etc.

Comment: Obviously you're using BeautifulSoup with Python, you can _only_ use BeautifulSoup with Python.

Comment: @CRUSADER I definitely wouldn't go that far.  The approach would have to be differnet for straight data scraping, but there are many machine learning projects that do exactly this, processing news on the fly.  It's definitely harder for an individual developer, but I wouldn't call it "nonsense."

Comment: Every site will format their pages differently.  The best you could do would be some sort of best guess heuristic, but that would be pretty complex.  Why are you trying to strip story content wholesale from news sites anyway?  Sounds a little suspect to me...

Comment: I agree it's not a 'nonsense', and although certainly very difficult in general, even imperfect heuristics can be useful.

Comment: The idea is broken by design .to make it clear

Comment: Thanks for following up like a boss. Gold Star.

Comment: Also I think the author of the question might like to mention his own (?) https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper - a somewhat extended goose in python 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might look at the [python-readability](https://github.com/buriy/python-readability) package which does exactly this for you.

Answer (score 3):

You're really not going about it the right way, I would say, as all the comments above would attest to.

That said, this does what you're looking for.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
html = requests.get('http://www.cnn.com/2013/01/04/justice/ohio-rape-online-video/index.html?hpt=hp_c2').text
soup = BS(html)
print '\n\n'.join([k.text for k in soup.find(class_='cnn_strycntntlft').find_all('p')])
```

It pulls out only the text, first by finding the main container of all the `<p>` tags, then by selecting only the `<p>` tags themselves to get the text; ignoring the `<script>` and other irrelevant ones.

As was mentioned in the comments, this will only work for CNN--and possibly, only this page.  You might need a different strategy for every new webpage.

Comment: Thanks for responding & trying to help, despite this not being a generic solution.

Comment: There is no such thing as a generic solution, is the point.  Creating such a generic solution requires a huge project involving machine learning and artificial intelligence.

Comment: You could come up with something fairly course grained that would be better than a straight crawler by analyzing page elements and trying to find large text blocks in page elements with similar types and/or attributes, but if you want something that won't have a fairly high miss and false-positive rate, yeah, you'll need some pretty serious AI.

Comment: @ sr22, i'll implement what you said above and look at the miss rates, maybe with fine tuning something like this can be made into something reliable. @CRUSADER, what are you so annoyed about? You talk as if coding something up like this is impossible.

Comment: @CRUSADER I think it would be beneficial for the OP to hear what you have to say is exactly wrong with his approach and what different ways he can approach it.

Comment: There isn't always an easy but-do-it-this-way answer. Pointing out that an approach is naive or far beyond the skills of the OP is also an answer - or at least a very valid recommendation. In this case: the approach is naive, too naive for working properly and reliable in reality and some alternative have been mentioned.